# How to map foreign key without object attribute?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have table that has a foreign key reference to an other. At JPA there are sample that maps class attributes but what I want to do is just hold string identifier for reference (not object) at my java class.

How can I do this? Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Sample Code:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private long id;

    // I want to have managerId here instead of Employee object.
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Employee manager;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Lets say your foreign key column is `employee_id`. So it will be like below if you don't want to map it with Object.

```
@column(name="employee_id")
private Long manager;
```

Comment: Hello, I also want to delete employe when the manager is deleted. The sample is not logical but I need foreign key cascade.
Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: You can not cascade if you do not use any relation.